# Cannot find type System.Security.CodeAccessPermission

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am developing an application in Xamarin Forms using Visual Studio 2017.
Only when I ran the UWP project following error appeared in the error list.

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(375,5):  Xaml Internal Error error
>   WMC9999: Cannot find type System.Security.CodeAccessPermission in
>   module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary

Comment: Checking installed NuGet Package ,removing not used or installing need used.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, Thank you for the reply,
I have installed all packages which are used in the app

Comment: 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(406,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.Security.CodeAccessPermission in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary